# Populate ComboBox from XML

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, combobox

I'm trying to populate a Combobox in C# using a field from my XML file, but with no luck... I don't know what is wrong here (it doesn't show anything):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("Baza_de_cunostinte.xml");

        var dataSource = new List<Persoane>();
        string PersoanaPlacuta;

        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
        {
            string persoanaPlacuta = node["PersoanaPlacuta"].InnerText.Replace("\"", "");

            comboBox1.Items.Add(persoanaPlacuta);
        }
     }
```

This is the XML file:

```
 <root>
  <Persoane>
    <Nume>"Bob"</Nume>
    <IsMale>true</IsMale>
    <Varsta>30</Varsta>
    <PersoanaPlacuta>"Iulia"</PersoanaPlacuta>
  </Persoane>

  <Persoane>
    <Nume>"Bogdan"</Nume>
    <IsMale>true</IsMale>
    <Varsta>28</Varsta>
    <PersoanaPlacuta>"Ana"</PersoanaPlacuta>
  </Persoane>

</root>
```

Comment: You are changing the items when user changes the selected item, So basically, the selected item is always changing.

Comment: Also show your XML to be more clear with your question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your are searching in the right Xml node address. You should do it with the full address in order to find the targeted node.

Use `XmlNodeList` to get all the nodes with the full address and then loop through its items:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("Baza_de_cunostinte.xml");

    var dataSource = new List<Persoane>();
    string PersoanaPlacuta;


     XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//root//Persoane");
     foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodeList)
     {
        string PersoanaPlacuta = node.ChildNodes[3].InnerText.Replace("\"", "");
        comboBox1.Items.Add(PersoanaPlacuta);
     }
}
```

Also you can change the `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach (string PersoanaPlacuta in from XmlNode node in xmlNodeList 
                            select node.ChildNodes[3].InnerText.Replace("\"", ""))
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(PersoanaPlacuta);
}
```

**Note**: You better add `comboBox1.Items.Clear();` at the first line, otherwise you will get repetitive items in your ComboBox

Comment: I've used "string persoanaPlacuta = node["PersoanaPlacuta"].InnerText.Replace("\"", ""); " to show the names in a ListBox and it worked....

Comment: @user3063909 So *it worked* or *still not showing anything*?

Comment: @user3063909 You really need to set a breakpoint and start debugging your code. cause this code works fine in my example app.